# Collision and collada meshes

Tags: collision, collada

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using .dae meshes for my robot and it seems that when I define the collision tag using that mesh, objects can just go through and no collision is simulated. Why is that?
example of my urdf

```
<link name="disk${index}">
  <visual>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="package://maru_simulation/meshes/disk.dae"/>
    </geometry>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.01" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </visual>
<inertial>
  <mass value="0.01" />
  <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
  iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0"
  izz="1.0" />
</inertial>
  <collision>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="package://maru_simulation/meshes/disk.dae"/>
    </geometry>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.01" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </collision>
</link>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8830/collision-and-collada-meshes/) by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 94 on 2015-05-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1014/marguedas/) on 2015-05-29**:
I don't have an answer but usually collada meshes are used for visualization. Textureless format with less vertices are usually used for collision, format as stl are best suited for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I figured out that models loaded from urdf's have by default "self collide" set to false so any joint from that model won't collide with any other joint, but if you spawn another object and make it collide with your mesh model, the simulator will take into consideration the collision.

---

Originally posted by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) with karma: 94 on 2018-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1